# OGR shapefile point example C#

Tags: c#, shapefile, gdal, qgis, osgeo

I am following [this](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/createdata.cs) code example which (according to my understanding) creates a shapefile with a point layer and adds a point at co-ordinates (47 and 19.2). When I run this code, it creates a shapefile (all three files with .dbf, .shp and .shx extensions). However, when I open the resulting .shp file in QGIS, I can not see any point at the given co-ordinates. This is what I have tried out so far.

1) The problem can be in either the code or QGIS. For QGIS, I have tried writing a code in C++ and the resulting shapefiles get displayed properly. In addition, I have downloaded various shapefiles from the internet and have successfully visualized them in QGIS

2) For the sample code, after making the shapefiles, the code reads the features in them and displays them (report layer/ report feature methods). These functions print the point at coordinates 47 and 19.2, which makes me think the code is working fine.

I can not pinpoint what is it that I'm doing wrong. I want to visualize the point in QGIS. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 3 files, that mean that the spatial reference is not define, and when you open it with QGis maybe the default spatial reference system involved that you can see the points at the good place.
If you the attribute table in QGIs, do you see something ?

Comment: That only matters when you want the user to display layers with different CRSs and have them overlay properly.